# OmniFaces 2.0 "Required CDI" error even though CDI is used

Tags: cdi, omnifaces

I'm using OmniFaces 1.6 currently, with an application running JSF 2.2.6, Weld 1.1.9, on a Tomcat 7.

I've tried updating OmniFaces to 2.0, but when I do, I get this error message while launching the application (and the application doesn't start):

> This OmniFace version requires CDI, but none was found on this environment. OmniFaces 2.x requires a minimum of JSF 2.2

It links to this page: http://omnifaces.org/cdi/

The problem is that, as I said, the application definitely uses JSF 2.2 and CDI.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: OmniFaces 2.0 requires CDI 1.1 (i.e. minimum Weld 2.x). The page also says *"When installing Weld, make sure that you're using a minimum of version 2.2.0! Older versions have initialization ordering bugs."* Try upgrading Weld first. 1.1.9 is way too old.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: I haven't had the time to actually get started with upgrading CDI just yet, so I can also upgrade OmniFaces. I'll make sure to post again when I've tried it to let you know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with you.

Please check this

http://omnifaces.org/cdi/

here are the additional instructions:

> 1. Install CDI 1.1+ in this environment.
>
> For Tomcat users who don't have freedom in server choice, refer this
>   article: How to install CDI in Tomcat?  When installing Weld, make
>   sure that you're using a minimum of version 2.2.0! Older versions have
>   initialization ordering bugs.
>
> 2. Switch to a CDI 1.1 capable environment.
>
> For Tomcat users who have full freedom in server choice, just replace
>   Tomcat by TomEE, or perhaps even by WildFly.